# Composer hangs on exit

Tags: laravel, symfony, composer-php

The execution of composer (install, update, create-project...) hangs after composer has finished with an blinking cursor and idle cpu - but the batch script won't exit. It is possible to end the process with ctrl+c.

The problem occurs for most of my Laravel and Symfony Projects and seems not to depended on a certain composer.json / .lock

- Window 10
- XAMPP PHP 7.0.18
- Un/reinstalled composer several times.

Examples:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel testapp
cd testapp
composer install
```

both won't exit

using --profile shows the following result:

```
C:\dev\killme>composer install --profile
[7.2MB/0.01s] Loading composer repositories with package information
[7.5MB/0.01s] Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
[8.5MB/0.04s] Nothing to install or update
[7.7MB/0.05s] Generating optimized autoload files
[9.6MB/7.26s] > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
[11.0MB/7.28s] > @php artisan package:discover
[11.1MB/7.69s] Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Package manifest generated successfully.
[10.0MB/7.71s] Memory usage: 9.99MB (peak: 11.53MB), time: 7.71s
- (blinking cursor - batch won't end)
^C cancel batch process (Y/N)? ^C
```

Comment: I tried to add an echo output in the composer.bat file, it seems that the php composer.phar itself hangs
@echo OFF
:: in case DelayedExpansion is on and a path contains ! 
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
echo finished

Comment: when omitting the batch script and calling php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar install - nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

The following change worked for me:

Updating from PHP 7.0.18 to 7.1.11 (XAMPP)